# %JAVA_HOME% env variable is recognized by Windows 7 Command Prompt, but java command doesn't work

Tags: java, windows-7, java-home

Here's the deal. My JAVA_HOME env variable looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
```

If I modify my Path variable like this

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

then the `java -version` will give this output, indicating that `java` keyword isn't recognized:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However, if I omit the JAVA_HOME variable and instead put JDK location in Path directly, like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

then it actually works:

> openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
>
> OpenJDK 64-bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

JAVA_HOME variable works fine, `cd %JAVA_HOME%` transports me to the right place and `echo %JAVA_HOME%` shows me this:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2

So why can't it work when it comes to finding java.exe?

I assumed that the space within path to JDK spoils everything and tried using this path instead

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.2
```

but no, same result.

P.S. I use Windows 7 Ultimate x64, in case it matters. And yes, I tried rebooting it.

Comment: Java itself doesn't use JAVA_HOME. Only things like IDEs, Tomcat, use it. All Java needs is the correct entry on the PATH.

Comment: Possibly due to https://superuser.com/questions/27826/why-cant-windows-handle-an-environment-variable-in-path